# Android Spinner's getSelectedView() returns null

Tags: android, view, android-spinner

I am trying to get a selected view of my spinner but it is returning null as all the time.

```
spinner.getSelectedView()
```

Any idea?

Comment: That should work. Does the spinner have a selected item?

Comment: Can you provide more code? A short, self contained snippet that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Figured was trying to access getSeletedView() before setting selection duh :( –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in my case it was timing issue as the getSelectedView() was called before setting selection. That explains why I was getting the view as null.

Answer (score 1):

Even after setting the view `spinner.getSelectedView()` was returning `null` for me.

As a workaround, I used the following code which worked for me and returned the correct view for some reason.

```
new Handler().post(() -> ((TextView)mVehicleView.getSelectedView()).setTextColor(context.getColor(R.color.gray2)));
```

If someone can explain why this happened, it would be great.

Posting this incase it happens to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the view, do you? I think this is what you want:

```
Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
String text = s.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: No I need a view specifically, so that I can modify it.

Comment: Ah. I'm a bit confused then. You want the view that the spinner has selected? Because your code should work in that case.

Comment: Figured was trying to access getSeletedView() before setting selection duh :(

Comment: @VendettaDroid Great! Glad you figured it out